# Let $X$ be a closed set of $E^n$. Let $Y$ be a closed set of $E^n$. Let $C$ be a closed set of $X$. Then, $C$ is a closed set of $X \cup Y$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I am reading a topology book (in Japanese) written by Yukio Matsumoto.
This is the definition of a closed set of a metric space $X$ in this book:

> Let $X$ be a metric space.
> Let $C \subset X$.
> $C$ is called a closed set of $X$ if $C$ satisfies the following property:
> Let $\{p_n\}$ be any sequence in $C$.
> If $\{p_n\}$ as a sequence in $X$ converges to $p_0 \in X$, then $p_0 \in C$.

I proved the following fact as follows.
Is my proof correct?

> Let $E^n$ be the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space.
> Let $X$ be a closed set of $E^n$.
> Let $Y$ be a closed set of $E^n$.
> Let $C$ be a closed set of $X$.
> Then, $C$ is a closed set of $X \cup Y$.

My proof:
Let $\{p_n\}$ be a sequence in $X$.
Suppose that $\{p_n\}$ as a sequence in $X \cup Y$ converges to $p_0 \in X \cup Y$.
Then $\{p_n\}$ as a sequence in $E^n$ converges to $p_0 \in E^n$.
Since $X$ is a closed set of $E^n$, $p_0 \in X$.
Therefore $X$ is a closed set of $X\cup Y$.

Let $\{q_n\}$ be a sequence in $C$.
Suppose that $\{q_n\}$ as a sequence in $X\cup Y$ converges to $q_0 \in X\cup Y$.
$\{q_n\}$ is a sequence in $X$ and $X$ is a closed set of $X\cup Y$, so $q_0 \in X$.
$\{q_n\}$ as a sequence in $X$ converges to $q_0 \in X$.
Since $C$ is a closed set of $X$, $q_0 \in C$.
Therefore $C$ is a closed set of $X\cup Y$.